# Date on iOS device returns NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, webkit

i'm currently developing a cordova web based application with ionic and angularjs. now i've created a service that returns a formatted time the way my client wants it.. the problem with this is that whilst it works on android and in browser, it displays NaN on an iOS device. The date i insert is from a database in timestamp : NOW() format, is there a fix for this? 
this is my date service:

```
.factory('displaydate',['$filter', function($filter) {
  return function (date){
    var maandarray = new Array('Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'); 
    var actiondate = new Date(date);
    var today = new Date();
    if(today.getDate() == actiondate.getDate()){
        var hourssince =   today.getHours() - actiondate.getHours()
        var minutessince =   today.getMinutes() - actiondate.getMinutes()
        var secondssince =   today.getSeconds() - actiondate.getSeconds()
        if(hourssince > 0){
            date = hourssince+'u';
        }else if(minutessince > 0){
            date = minutessince+'m';
        }else{
            date = secondssince+'s';
        }
    }else{
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((today.getTime() - actiondate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
        if(diffDays > 28){
            var identifier = actiondate.getMonth() - 1;
            var month = maandarray[identifier];
            date = $filter('date')(actiondate,"d ") + month +  $filter('date')(actiondate," yy " + " HH:" + "mm");
        }else{ 
            date = diffDays+'d';
        }
    }
    return date;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: It probably means that the "date" string you start off with is not understood as a valid date format in iOS. If you construct a Date instance with an unparseable string, then all the APIs return `NaN`.

Comment: You should format the string in a standard format (ISO) and i'm pretty sure that it will work

Comment: it's a mysql timestamp NOW() format string straight from the db

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit That produces a datetime that is close to ISO8601, but not exactly. If you want it to be parsed correctly in all browsers, you need to format it, or parse it yourself (or with a library)

Comment: Thanks @Ian formatting it indeed fixed it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fixed this thanks to @Ian his comment ,

changed this:

```
var actiondate = new Date(date);
```

to this:

```
var t = date.split(/[- :]/);

// Apply each element to the Date function
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
var actiondate = new Date(d);
```

Comment: nice thanks, for json date format `var t = date.split(/[- : T]/);` and dont forget to parseInt() for each element of the array `new Date(parseInt(t[0]), parse...`

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd! Held!

Answer (score 13):

The reason of the problem is iPhone Safari doesn't support the `Y-m-d H:i:s` (ISO 8601) date format. I have encountered this problem in 2017/7/19, I do not understand why Safari did not fix the problem after two years.

I refer to the answer of Sjoerd, thanks Sjoerd, just rewrite it to a function to do the date conversion when you have many date need to be processed. After you get a date(**must be `Y-m-d H:i:s` format**) from server, you could use the function convert the date to the format which iOS device could resolve and other browsers could resolve too.

```
function convertDateForIos(date) {
    var arr = date.split(/[- :]/);
    date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    return date;
}
```

I encountered the problem when I write ajax for date, hope the solution will help others encountered the annoying problem.

Comment: I keep getting an error "date.split is not a function" ... any idea why?

Comment: @CJBroersma It could be your `date` is not a valid `Y-m-d H:i:s` (ISO 8601) date format. Check it and format the `date`.

Comment: oh thanks, I missed some server side code that did change it. Thanks for the great function.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
var actiondate = new Date(date.replace(" ", "T"));
```

Answer (score -3):

install momentjs to  by 
**npm install moment --save**

intitilize the new date with 
var date  = moment(yourDate).format() 
var formatedDate  = new data(date)

hope this resolve the issue

Comment: This is dependent on a library for one simple function. I suggest reading this: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs